# Joomla 3 NavBar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I am having a problem with displaying my navbar within my Joomla 3 website when resized to a tablet/mobile size.

For some reason I have a grey nav button appearing on the left and when i click this a blue nav bar appears on the right hand side with the menu then dropping down.

How can i make it so that I have either the grey or blue box and then when clicked the dropdown appears but all from one side.

I am confused as to why both are appearing.

When checking with firebug, I can see that one is navbar pull-left class and the other class is nav-collapse.

Comment: Try to be more specific.
You are using bootstrap? that version?
You can include a URL?

Comment: Hi apologies, I am using bootstrap with the latest joomla 3.4 version, Unfortunately the site is on my localhost at the mo hence not able to share a URL...

Answer (score 0):

There are several variables to deal in this matter.

First, make sure version of bootstrap want to use and what you're really using.

Second, if you want to use the bootstrap version 3, make sure it is not charging well, version 2, which is the default Joomla brings. This will you manage in your template.

Third, you may also need an override of template for the code generated by joomla, run right.

I leave part of the code that you need for all this.

Get bootstrap 3 in joomla template. Copy js and css files to directorys and...

```
$doc->addScript($tpath.'/js/bootstrap.min.js');
$doc->addStyleSheet($tpath.'/css/bootstrap_3.css');
```

To avoid conflicts, how not to load js files it is as follows:

```
unset($doc->_scripts[$this->baseurl.'/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js']);
```

In this case, we remove the bootstrap.min.js joomla file loaded by default.